# Change td cell colour based on a number typed into an input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form.  In the form I have number input fields.  The minimum number is 1 and the maximum is 5.  All good so far.  The use puts in a number (between 1-5) based on a risk assessment. 1 being low risk and 5 being high risk.  If the user puts in a 1 I want the cell that the input field is in to turn green.  If they input 5 I want it to turn red.  The colour can start as green when the form first appears (though I am happy for it to be no colour until the field is first populated)  numbers 1 and 2 are both green. 3 changes to yellow 4 to orange then 5 to red. Sounds simple enough but Im a little lost.  Can someone take me by the hand and lead me through it.  I have researched it but I have not found anything that gets me any closer.

Comment: What code have you tried?  What does your HTML look like?  SO is not a free code writing service, but we can help solve problems you are having with code you've written.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Grab the form.

```
var form = document.querySelector('#form');
```

We're going to use event delegation - attaching the event listener to the parent element to catch events that bubble up from its children rather than attach on to each input element. When a key is pressed in an input, call `changeColor`.

```
form.addEventListener('keyup', changeColor, false);
```

Array of colors.

```
var colors = ['green', 'green', 'orange', 'orange', 'red'];
```

`e.target` is the element that caused the event to fire. Set its background color to the corresponding one from the array.

```
function changeColor(e) {
  var input = e.target;
  input.style.backgroundColor = colors[input.value - 1];
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8xrx6mrc/7/)

Comment: Not sure I deserved that downvote.

Comment: [link]http://hama.com.au/mi6/riskass.php is where Im trying to use it. the consequence rating field has been set up to do it but it doenst.  My form is called formrisk and the event handler has been changed to reflect that.  I did it in your demo Andy and it worked fine there but when I put the code in my document it doesnt and cant work out why. The code does exactly what I need to do if only I can work out what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Move that code block just before `</body>`. At the moment it's trying to find an element that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: that did the trick thanks Andy